# How to compute for the coordinates of polynomial function?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

This is a multi-part question and im now in the part where coordinates are involved but i'm not sure how to proceed with this.

[image]

I was already able to answer up to 2a but not sure how to proceed with 2b. Could anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: It is a pain to compute the coefficients of a vector in a general basis but, for orthonormal bases, it is a walk in the park :  $$u=\sum_i\langle u, e_i \rangle e_i.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Calculate $L(5t^2-t+2) = 5t+5 = p1$.
You have $B = ${$p2=t-2, p3=3t$} 
Now you are looking for $α$ and $β$ that will hold:
$$p1=α*p2+β*p3$$
And then $[p1]_B = (α,β)$
You can see that:
$$p1=-2\frac12*p2+2\frac12*p3$$
And these are the coordinates.

Comment: How did you get 5t + 5? And what exactly are p1, p2 and p3?

Comment: @Duts It is given in the question, $L(at^2+bt+c) = (at +2c -b)$, thus in our case $L(5t^2-t+2) = 5t+5$. I just named the polynomials so it will be easier to write. $p1=5t+5$ and p2,p3 are the 2 polynomials defining your base in the question.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand how you got 5 in 5t + 5.

Comment: you have $a=5,b=(-1),c=2$. $L(5t^2−t+2)=(5t+4-(-1)=5t+5$

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: I have another question. Is it right that my augmented matrix to solve the equation is something like this: [1 3 5; -2 0 5]?